If $f(n) = f_1(n) + f_2(n) + \cdots + f_{n-1}(n)$ and $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} f_i = O(n)$, does $f=O(n^2)$?
I am wondering whether the following claim is true: if $f$ maps from the positive integers to the positive reals and $f(n) = f_1(n) + f_2(n) + \cdots + f_{n-1}(n)$ where the $f_i$ are any functions having the same domain and codomain as $f$ and $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} f_i = O(n)$, then $f = O(n^2)$. The reason why I am asking is that I seemed to have proved it false, but my textbook simplifies $\underbrace{O(n)+O(n)+\cdots+O(n)}_{n-1 \text { times }}$ to $O(n^2)$, leading me to believe there was a mistake in my
"proof"; so the claim whose truth I am inquiring is my attempt to formalize the rule behind the simplification which my textbook did. The reason why I was seeing that we couldn't make such a simplification was because if the smallest constant $c$ which makes $f_i<=cn$ gets bigger as $i$ increases, then our only info is that $f(n) \le c(n-1)(n)$, and because $c$ gets arbitrarily large it seems like there can't exist a single constant $k$ such that $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}   c(n-1)n \le k \cdot n^2$ is true for all $n$ after a certain point, as if we take $c = n$ then  $c(n-1)(n) = n^2(n-1)$, and this will eventually exceed $k\cdot n^2$.
However, because the textbook makes this simplification, I doubted my reasoning. So is this claim true and if so, where did I go wrong in my reasoning?

Your intuition is correct; if $f_i(n) = i n$ then each of the $f_i$ are $O(n)$ but $$ f(n) = 1n + 2n + \cdots + (n-1)n = n \sum_1^{n-1} i = \frac{n^2-n}2 n $$ is not $O(n^2)$.
The natural requirement that would allow us to make this simplification would be if the implicit constants in the various $O(n)$'s are bounded by some global constant $C$.

I don't think the constants being bounded by some global constant is enough: for example, if you let $f_i(n) = \begin{cases} n^3, & n = i+1, \ n, & n \ne i+1 \end{cases}$ then each $f_i(n) = O(n)$ with constant 1, but $f_1(n) + \cdots + f_{n-1}(n) > (n-1)^3$ so the sum is not $O(n^2)$.  So you would also need some condition on the $n_0$ where the inequality starts being true, such as perhaps that the $n_0$ are also bounded by a global constant $N_0$.

@DanielSchepler what is the reason why the sum is bigger than $(n-1)^3$- for which $n$ does the occur?

Oh, OK, $f_{n-1}(n) = n^3$ so $f_1(n) + \cdots + f_{n-1}(n) > n^3$ was what I should have written.

@DanielSchepler I don't understand- are you revising your original scenario to be one where where the $f_{n-1}=n^3$ on its entire domain?

@PrincessMia No, I'm using the same functions $f_i$, just updating a small detail in the explanation of why $f_1(n) + \cdots + f_{n-1}(n)$ is not $O(n^2)$.

@DanielSchepler but by construction $f_{n-1} = O(n)$- is this not contradicted by your example of $f_{n-1} = n^3$?
